# Forecast package Prediction Horizon issue in R

Tags: r, forecasting, prediction

I am new to R. I was trying to predict using holt method but getting this strange error. I am using forecast package V-7.1 with R (version 3.2.5) and Rstudio (Version 0.99.896). I reinstall all from R to Rstudio but did not work. Only h from 1 to 10 works. Any idea??

```
  library(forecast)
  library(stats)
  library(base)
  x=data$cost
  k<-holt(x,damped=TRUE)
  m=forecast(k,h=20)

  Error in forecast.forecast(k, h = 20) : 
  Please select a longer horizon when the forecasts are first computed
```

Other testing cases:

```
 m=forecast(k,h=2000)
 Error in forecast.forecast(k, h = 2000) : 
 Please select a longer horizon when the forecasts are first computed

 m=forecast(k,h=10)
 m=forecast(k,h=11)
 Error in forecast.forecast(k, h = 11) : 
 Please select a longer horizon when the forecasts are first computed

 m=forecast(k,h=100)
 Error in forecast.forecast(k, h = 100) : 
 Please select a longer horizon when the forecasts are first computed
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the `h` parameter in the call to `holt()`, not in the call to `forecast()`.

`holt()` fits a model *and* computes the forecast. This is in contrast to "typical" R usage and other forecasting-related functions, like `ets()`, `arima()` etc. So you don't even need to call `forecast()` on the output of `holt()`:

```
> print(holt(airmiles,h=15))
     Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95    Hi 95
1961       32772.01 31455.62 34088.39 30758.77 34785.24
1962       34877.47 32594.37 37160.56 31385.77 38369.16
1963       36982.93 33767.27 40198.59 32065.00 41900.85
1964       39088.39 34912.84 43263.94 32702.44 45474.34
1965       41193.85 36015.50 46372.21 33274.24 49113.47
1966       43299.31 37070.39 49528.24 33773.00 52825.63
1967       45404.78 38076.33 52733.23 34196.88 56612.67
1968       47510.24 39033.57 55986.91 34546.29 60474.19
1969       49615.70 39942.98 59288.42 34822.56 64408.84
1970       51721.16 40805.71 62636.62 35027.41 68414.91
1971       53826.62 41622.95 66030.30 35162.71 72490.53
1972       55932.09 42395.93 69468.25 35230.32 76633.86
1973       58037.55 43125.82 72949.27 35232.03 80843.06
1974       60143.01 43813.77 76472.25 35169.60 85116.42
1975       62248.47 44460.85 80036.09 35044.65 89452.29
```

Comment: Thanks :)  it works but could you explain to me what is the difference between holt and "Holt" of package aTSA. Which one I should use for my data both have them same MAPE value.

Comment: Both implement [Holt's exponential smoothing with a linear trend](https://www.otexts.org/fpp/7/2). There may be differences in the details of the implementation, but those should not matter. Go with whatever you want. (I would be tempted to trust `forecast::holt()` a *tiny* bit more, because I know its author Rob Hyndman and trust his work - I have never heard of the author of the aTSA package and can't vouch for him.)