# Exponential smoothing forecasting with %Y-%m-%d %H:%M time series format in R

Tags: r, time-series, xts, forecasting, smoothing

I have short time series for traffic flow and I want to predict the traffic flow using Simple Exponential Smoothing methods for a comparison with ARIMA Model.

I've finished ARIMA model part but I'm stuck with how to format the data in order to apply the Simple Exponential Smoothing model.

The reason why I'm using Simple Exponential Smoothing is because I read it works with short time series where there's no trend or seasonality. 
My time series is for 4 months and has hourly reading.

my data looks like this :

```
       Date_Hour       Traffic_Flow      
2017-07-17 00:00:00         50 
2017-07-17 01:00:00         80 
2017-07-17 02:00:00         77 
2017-07-17 03:00:00         89 
2017-07-17 04:00:00         61 
2017-07-17 05:00:00         64
```

I've 2175 observations, and for the training will use 1522 observations (3/4) of the data, and for the testing will use 653 observations.

```
View(SES_Data)
SES_DataXTS <- as.xts(x= SES_Data[,-1], order.by = as.POSIXct(SES_Data$Date_Hour), frequency = 4)
# Split the Data
training_indices <- 1:floor(0.7 * nrow(SES_DataXTS))
training_data <- SES_DataXTS[training_indices]
test_data <- SES_DataXTS[-training_indices]
#Fit mode:
fit_Model_SES <- ses(training_data ,beta=FALSE, gamma=FALSE)
# Do forecasting
forecast_SES <- forecast(fit_Model_SES,h=653)
```

When I do the forecasting , I get this error:

```
Error in forecast.forecast(fit_Model_SES, h = 653) : 
  Please select a longer horizon when the forecasts are first computed
```

How do I specify the start and end when I have hourly reading in my data?
I couldn't find example of how to use Simple Exponential Smoothing with xts and zoo object.
And if I converted my data into ts(), it will ignore the hourly reading.

I tried this command but I don't think it correct.

```
tsfunction <- ts(SES_Data, frequency=24, start=2017-07-17 00:00:00, end= 2017-10-15 14:00:00, beta=FALSE, gamma=FALSE)
```

Any suggestions please? Or any other forecasting technique I can use with short time series to compare it with ARIMA

Updates:

So I edit my command into:

```
#Fit mode:
fit_Model_SES <- ses(SES_DataXTS ,beta=FALSE, gamma=FALSE, h=653)
#fit_Model_SES <- ses(training_data1 ,beta=FALSE, gamma=FALSE, h = 653)    
#Model 1: Exponential State Smoothing
f_ets = forecast(fit_Model_SES) # forecast 4 months into the future
plot(f_ets, col="blue")
```

But when I plot my forecast it reads my date time format incorrect.

like this:
[image]

I'm looking for plotting my forecast as I did with ARIMA model with the same data like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the `h` parameter in the function `ses()` (it will compute the forecast). For some functions, like `ses()`, you don't need to call `forecast()` after.

```
forecast_SES <- forecast(fit_Model_SES, h = 600)
```

Source: [Forecast package Prediction Horizon issue in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36922955/forecast-package-prediction-horizon-issue-in-r)

Comment: Thank you! I checked the link before but couldn't figure out how to get the forecasting results with the actual results .

Comment: can you validate the answer if it corresponds to your needs ?